# what is a good pattern to processes each individual regex match through a method

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to figure out a pattern where I run a regex match on a long string, and each time it finds a match, it runs a replace on it. The thing is, the replace will vary depending on the matched value. This new value will be determined by a method. For example:

```
var matches = Regex.Match(myString, myPattern);
while(matches.Success){
   Regex.Replace(myString, matches.Value, GetNewValue(matches.Groups[1]));
   matches = matches.NextMatch();
}
```

The problem (i think) is that if I run the Regex.Replace, all of the match indexes get messed up so the result ends up coming out wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Regex only works because of the fact it needs to match patterns. If you're breaking the patterns, you're breaking the need for Regex.

Comment: How is the pattern being broken. The pattern stays the same, its the source that I might breaking since I'm replacing the matches. And regex provides the Replace function, so I don't believe I've negated the need for Regex at all

Comment: That was my point. You're breaking the source, therefore, your patterns may also be broken according to the Regex engine..

Comment: `Regex.Rplace` replaces all the matches. No need to iterate to the next.

Comment: @SinaIravanian I think the OP is changing the source each time though.. that was my understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace each pattern with a fixed string, `Regex.replace` does that for you. You don't need to iterate the matches:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, myPattern, "replacement");
```

Otherwise, if the replacement depends upon the matched value, use the `MatchEvaluator` delegate, as the 3rd argument to `Regex.Replace`. It receives an instance of `Match` and returns `string`. The return value is the replacement string. If you don't want to replace some matches, simply return `match.Value`:

```
string myString = "aa bb aa bb";
string myPattern = @"\w+";
string result = Regex.Replace(myString, myPattern, 
                      match => match.Value == "aa" ? "0" : "1" );
Console.WriteLine(result);
// 0 1 0 1
```

If you really need to iterate the matches and replace them manually, you need to start replacement from the last match towards the first, so that the index of the string is not ruined for the upcoming matches. Here's an example:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, myPattern);
var matchesFromEndToStart = matches.Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Index);
var sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
foreach (var match in matchesFromEndToStart)
{
    if (IsGood(match))
    {
        sb.Remove(match.Index, match.Length)
          .Insert(match.Index, GetReplacementFor(match));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Just be careful, that your matches do not contain nested instances. If so, you either need to remove matches which are inside another match, or rerun the regex pattern to generate new matches after each replacement. I still recommend the second approach, which uses the delegates.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't even notice that overload. Thank you.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic For the sake of completeness, I added another example which uses the loop, and starts from the last towards the first.

Comment: I was actually able to use the delegate to call my function that get's the new value: match => GetNewValue(match.Group[1].ToString())

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to perform a replace based on a constant Regular Expression, but the replacement text you use will change based on the actual text that the regex matches on.

The Captures property of the Match Class (not the Match method) returns a collection of all the matches with your regex within the input string. It contains information like the position within the string, the matched value and the length of the match. If you iterate over this collection with a foreach loop you should be able to treat each match individually and perform some string manipulations where you can dynamically modify the replacement value.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
Regex regEx = new Regex("some.*?pattern");
string input = "someBLAHpattern!";
foreach (Match match in regEx.Matches(input))
{
    DoStuffWith(match.Value);
}
```