# REGEX character Set substitution

Tags: c#, regex

I need a RegEx pattern that will allow me to substitute characters from one set to their corresponding characters in another set. for example: set [abcdefg], should be replaced with set [1234567]... So in a string of "bag", i want my replacement to be "217".

```
Regex regX = new Regex("([abcdefg])([1234567])");
string result = regX.Replace("bag", "$1$2");
```

My result is same as source. What should my replace pattern be?

Comment: Regex identifies a sequence of characters in a string. It isn't responsible for replacing characters. However, you can retrieve the length and index of the matched string using regex and with that you can replace a string with `vsprintf` or whatever replacement C# offers.

Comment: Using a RegEx is one of the more inappropriately complex solutions to this problem.  Is there a reason you can't use a for loop to look at each character and use a StringBuilder to concatenate the new characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work much better than a Regex:

```
var fromCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var toCharacters = "12345678901234567890123456";

var myString = "bag";

var sb = new StringBuilder(myString.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; ++i)
{
    sb.Append(toCharacters[fromCharacters.IndexOf(myString[i])]);
}

sb.ToString().Dump();
```

You could do something similar if you want, for example, 'j' to turn into '10', but you would need an array of Strings instead of being able to use a String as an array of chars.

I'm not sure how you would do this with a Regex, but I do know that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
string result = Regex.Replace("abcdefghiABCDEFGHI", "[a-zA-Z]", 
    m => (('a' <=  m.Value[0] && m.Value[0] <= 'z' 
               ? m.Value[0] - 'a' 
               : m.Value[0] - 'A') + 1).ToString());

Console.WriteLine(result);
// 123456789123456789
```

I used the `MatchEvaluator` delegate to replace each match with the corresponding value.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699783/what-is-a-good-pattern-to-processes-each-individual-regex-match-through-a-method/14699923#14699923) for another example for it.

The problem with your pattern is that no one's expecting the numbers inside the input string, so it shouldn't be part of the pattern.

Comment: I had to upvote for managing to do it with a Regex, but that is a confusing way to write a loop and a letter check :)

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin completely agreed. I did that because he asked for a regex one. I would never do it with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `Dictionary<char, char>` for chars matching here:

```
var dict = "abcdefg"
    .Zip("1234567", (k, v) => new { k, v })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.k, i => i.v);
var result = string.Concat("bag".Select(c => dict[c]));
```

This will get you:

```
217
```

Answer (score -1):

You havent mentioned a language, I'll tell how to do it in php. You can fixup according to your needs.
In your case of replacement your parameters should be arrays.
$num = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
$chr = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
Then you can use either str_replace or preg_replace
$str = "This is a sample text";
 echo str_replace($chr, $num, $str);
You can use regexp as first parameter as pattern but NOT for astring in this case.

Comment: The language was in the tag - C# :)

Comment: Sory, I didn't notice the tag, I checked it in your message :(